# How can implement efficiently this subset enumeration problem?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of numbers `Sn = [a, b, c, d, ...]` and a set of non-overlapping intervals `Si = {I1, I2, I3, ...}`. Given that, my problem is to find the list `L` of subsets of `Sn` such that the sum of elements in each subset is bound into at least an interval inside `Si`.

My approach right now is to enumerate all the subsets of `Sn` and filter them based if they fit an interval. It is correct, but inefficient.

```py
import itertools

Sn = [12, 30, 60, 6, 6]
Si = {(12, 12), (18, 24), (30, 48)}

def enumerate_sets():
    sets = []
    for i in range(len(Sn)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(Sn, i + 1):
            for interval in Si:
                if interval[0] <= sum(comb) <= interval[1]:
                    sets.append(comb)
                    break
    return sets

print(enumerate_sets())
# [(12,), (30,), (12, 30), (12, 6), (12, 6), (30, 6), (30, 6), (6, 6), (12, 30, 6), (12, 30, 6), (12, 6, 6), (30, 6, 6)]
```

How can I efficiently implement this subset problem? Answers in python are prefered but any (pseudo)language will do.

Comment: What metric are you using to measure the "efficiency" of your program? Algorithmic complexity? Memory consumption? Actual running time?

Comment: @ethane Algorithmic complexity, although in the end its the runtime that matters, but I don't have the data about runtime on a sufficiently exhaustive sample

Comment: Please add your solution so that we can see the complexity of your solution and better answer the question.

Comment: Just to clarify- problem is to find the list L of **all** subsets of Sn? Or you want some particular number of them?

Comment: Also set of numbers means for you set of unique numbers, right?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Thanks for the checking, because in my actual problem the numbers are not unique. I edited to reflect that, and also added code.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski We don't want to stop at a particular number of subsets. We later select the best fit based on other criterias.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as for programming, python solution - this will do the trick:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def getL(Sn:np.ndarray, Si:np.ndarray):
    Si.sort(axis=0)
    Sn.sort()
    for i in range(1, len(Sn)+1):
        for s in combinations(Sn, i):
            su=sum(s)
            if((np.logical_and(Si[:,0]<=su, Si[:,1]>=su)).any()):
                yield s
```

Sample output:

```py
>>> # to convert your input into numpy:
>>> Sn = [12, 30, 60, 6, 6]
>>> Si = {(12, 12), (18, 24), (30, 48)}
>>> Sn = np.array(Sn)
>>> Si = np.array(list(Si))
>>> print(list(getL(Sn, Si)))

[(12,), (30,), (6, 6), (6, 12), (6, 30), (6, 12), (6, 30), (12, 30), (6, 6, 12), (6, 6, 30), (6, 12, 30), (6, 12, 30)]
```

Few notes - to save memory - generally using `generator` should be faster, so you won't just accumulate into `list`, but once you get something - you return, and forget it.
Use `numpy` - this will speed up browsing through the intervals significantly.

Comment: OP's `Sn` and `Si` aren't `np.ndarray`s... Can you also show the usage for this with OP's data?

Comment: Generators are actually generally slower than functions due to stack overhead. Whether or not it matters in OP's case is another thing :)

Comment: You right, if you have sufficient memory, and need to store the whole thing at once, this kind of thing can easily grow out proportion - that's way I suggested generator. Also if you are trying to find best fit - you just keep the best till now, compare it with next one, and keep the better fit. You don't have to store the whole thing ;)

Comment: Curiously, even though Numpy generally is fast, this benchmarks to be much slower than my solution below (when you actually iterate through it, of course).

Comment: By the way, isn't that `if(not anyres): break` condition wrong when there may be negative numbers in the list?

Comment: Nope - it's 0-1 variable. Yeah, I think you should see meaningful improvement with numpy, while increasing the size of interval set, however won't argue - might happen it will turn out slower for smaller sample data...

Comment: No, I mean the assumption that no match for N elements means no match for N+1 elements; what if the N+1th element decreases the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Since the sum of the combination is enough to know whether or not it's a valid combination, you can use it as a set key and avoid doing extra work.

`enumerate_sets_2` benchmarks to be (more than) 2x faster than the original here:

```
import timeit
import itertools
import collections

Sn = [12, 30, 60, 6, 6, 92, 443, -8, 112, 96]
Si = {(12, 12), (18, 24), (30, 48)}


def enumerate_sets_orig(Sn, Si):
    sets = []
    for i in range(len(Sn)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(Sn, i + 1):
            for interval in Si:
                if interval[0] <= sum(comb) <= interval[1]:
                    sets.append(comb)
                    break
    return sets


def enumerate_sets_2_iter(Sn, Si):
    valid_sums = set()
    for i in range(len(Sn)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(Sn, i + 1):
            comb_sum = sum(comb)
            if comb_sum in valid_sums:
                yield comb
                continue
            for a, b in Si:
                if a <= comb_sum <= b:
                    valid_sums.add(comb_sum)
                    yield comb
                    break



def make_comparable(result):
    # Make an enumerate_sets_* result comparable by sorting and removing duplicates
    return set(tuple(sorted(int(v) for v in i)) for i in result)


def t(f):
    # Wrap the function to evaluate generators and to pass in the args
    fw = lambda: list(f(Sn, Si))
    # Validate this solution before benchmarking
    assert expected == make_comparable(fw())
    # Benchmark
    count, time_taken = timeit.Timer(fw).autorange()
    print(f"{f.__name__:<25} {count / time_taken:>10.2f} iter/s")

expected = make_comparable(enumerate_sets_orig(Sn, Si))

t(enumerate_sets_orig)
t(enumerate_sets_2_iter)
```